# How to make a bat open a cmd window and run commands but stay open

Tags: batch-file

Help!

```
    Title Terminal-#$s 
color 0a 
Prompt PoodleCorp Console: 
cls
Echo Welcome, back.
```

I want that to be in a bat file and stay open for use of cmds

Comment: You could try running your batch with the `cmd` command with the option `/k` - [see here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Answer (score 0):

Prevent commands from showing

```
echo off
```

Set cmd window title

```
TITLE Welcome to the Matrix
```

Set cmd color

```
color 0a
```

Clear screen

```
cls
```

Display welcome message

```
cmd /k @echo "To deny our own impulses is to deny the very thing that makes us human."
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `cmd.exe` is called with the `/c` switch which **c**arries  out the command and then terminates.

The `/k` switch **k**arries out but *remains*, and lets you input commands (after executing the commands inside the batch file, ie the script, or directly given parameters after the commands as in `cmd /k "commands"`).

If you want to deny input to the user but still let the window hang you can append `pause > nul` at the end of the batch script.

It would just hang (pause) until the user responded, that is until the user presses *any key*, and after that exit.

The second part of the commands, tat is `nul` is to avoid the output "Press any key to continue..."

More here `cmd /?` or `help cmd`

[image]